# Cannot find the process using most of RAM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, process

I have 8 GB RAM running on Ubuntu. I notice that a lot of memory is used even when I don't run any programs. I used the `top` command to view the processes, sorted by resident memory they use. It showed that about 5GB was being used while the sum of memory used by processes are about < 20% of 8GB, which is about 1-2 GB.

Is there any possibility that some process using a lot of RAM is invisible from any program like `top`?

[image]

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use free -h to check the mount of the RAM used by cache and buffer.

Actually, it's a speed-up mechanism on Linux. If the RAM is free, it's useless. If we are able to use these free RAM to cache some data used frequently, it will speed up the whole system significantly. When some processes needs more RAM, these data will be swapped out from RAM.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the continuous suggestions.

Comment: @Ramhound Your answer is the best among all answers related to my questions that I have been looking at. Thks !

Comment: @MrCold - It isn't my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possibility that some process using a lot of RAM is
>   invisible from any program like top?

No - there will be no invisible processes.

`top` doesn't express 'free' as we might think of it. Sometimes the Operating System will cache memory and we would consider that memory 'free'. In short, there are no hiding processes and top is reporting things correctly.

See [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/top-used-memory-vs-ps-processes-memory-782765/) post for more info. I don't quite remember the in's and out's of memory reporting, but I do know that sorting by memory in top will show you the correct information and that there are no 'hiding' processes that are using more memory.